# How to use Exec / ExecFile on Javascript to run a java file and get the result

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

Running this JS file on the server side of my website so when the user presses a button, it executes this command with my API:

```
exports.runAlgorithm = async (req, res) => { 

    try {
        
        exec('java test.java', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`${error}`);
                return;
            }


            try {
                //Export the result to the database
                Result.create({
                    //Should send the algorithm's result here
                    result: stdout
                })
                res.send({
                    message: "Algorithm executed successfully and output stored in database",
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                res.send({
                    message: "Something went wrong when passing the data to the database",

                });
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

            }

        });

    }
    catch (err) {
        res.send({
            message: "Problem with running the algo"
        });
    }
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
exec error: Error: Command failed: java test.java
Error: Could not find or load main class test.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.java
```

[The API to run this code is the algorithm controller and the test file that just returns hello world is the test.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjFcc.png)

Have also tried the execFile alternative but to no avail. Perhaps I'm just using it wrongly or there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Java runs **compiled** files, with ".class" extension.
You should compile you test.java class using [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

```
javac test.java
```

Then, you should run java with the class name alone.

```
java test
```